# Скрипт на PowerShell

Tags: bash, unix, powershell

Как переписать этот скрипт на PowerShell

```
    #! /bin/sh
    c=$(ls -l -- "${1:-.}" | grep ^d | wc -l)
    printf "%u\t%s\n" $c "$1"
```

Comment: Ну, сначала напишите что он делает, пример входных и выходных данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разберём что делает скрипт

ls -l -- "${1:-.}" файлы директории в одноколоночном формате - тип файла, права доступа к файлу, количество ссылок на файл, имя владельца, имя группы, размер файла (в байтах), временной штамп и имя файла. Взять только первый столбец

grep ^d отобрать только строки соответствующие регулярке ^d то есть начинающиеся с "d" а это каталоги (потому что grep будет получать строки параметров вида "drwxr-xr-x" где первая буква "d" это каталог)

wc -l вывести количество строк отфильтрованных grep

c=$(ls -l -- "${1:-.}" | grep ^d | wc -l) положить результаты пайпа в переменную "c"

printf "%u\t%s\n" $c "$1" вывести $c в виде числа после чего вывести знак табуляции после чего вывести первый параметр переданный в скрипт в виде строки вывести символ перевода каретки

То есть скрипт просто выводит количество каталогов

То же самое на PowerShell

```
$directoryInfo = Get-ChildItem -Directory | Measure-Object
Write-Host $directoryInfo.count
```

Comment: К чему `Measure-Object`? Оверинжениринг? Достаточно `(Get-ChildItem -Directory).Count`